# Where does the normal to the graph of $y = \sqrt x$ at the point $(a, \sqrt a)$ intersect the $x$-axis?

Tags: calculus

> Where does the normal to the graph of $y = \sqrt x$ at the point $(a, \sqrt a)$ intersect the $x$-axis?

I know how to find equation with numbers, but got really confused with this one. If anybody could break it down it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I've done: Took derivative $= .5x^{-.5}$, then plugged in $x$ value $a$ to get $1/2a^{-1/2}$, so the slope of tangent is $1/2a^{-1/2}$? so the slope of normal is $2a^{-1/2}$? So $y-\sqrt{a} = 2a^{-1/2}(x-a)$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the slope of the line normal to the curve at $(a,\sqrt{a})$?  What did you find the line normal to the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ at the point $(a,\sqrt{a})$ to look like using that slope?  Did you try writing in point-slope form?  If you plug in $0$ for $y$ in the equation for that line, that corresponds to the point where it intersects the $x$-axis.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Here is what i've done. Took derivative = .5x^-.5.   then plugged in x value (a) to get 1/2a^-1/2. so the slope of tangent is 1/2a^-1/2? so the slope of normal is 2a^-1/2? So y-sqrta = 2a^-1/2(x-a)? I am confused.  Also thank you very much for quick response!!

Comment: The slope of the normal line is the *negative* reciprocal of the slope of the tangent line.  Fix that, then solve for $x$ when $y = 0$.

Comment: You have fallen victim to your own poor notation, it seems, and confused $1/2a^{-1/2}$ with $\dfrac{1}{2a^{-1/2}}$. Better to write $\frac12 a^{-1/2}$ or $\dfrac{1}{2a^{1/2}}$. (But $.5x^{-.5}$ is even worse!)

Answer (score 1):

The function $y = \sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ has derivative 
$$y' = \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ 
as you found.  The tangent line to the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ at the point $(a, \sqrt{a})$ has slope 
$$y'(a) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}$$
which is defined for $a > 0$.

You made a mistake when you calculated the slope of the normal line.  Since the normal line is perpendicular to the tangent line, its slope is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the tangent line.  Thus, the slope of the normal line is $-2\sqrt{a}$. Hence, the equation of the normal line at the point $(a, \sqrt{a})$ is 
$$y - \sqrt{a} = -2\sqrt{a}(x - a)$$
To solve for the $x$-intercept of the normal line, we set $y = 0$ and solve for $x$.
\begin{align*}
0 - \sqrt{a} & = -2\sqrt{a}(x - a)\\
-\sqrt{a} & = -2\sqrt{a}x + 2a\sqrt{a}\\
2\sqrt{a}x & = (2a + 1)\sqrt{a}\\
x & = a + \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*} 
Thus, for $a > 0$, the normal line to the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ at the point $(a, \sqrt{a})$ intersects the $x$-axis at the point $(a + \frac{1}{2}, 0)$.

Since 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \infty$$ 
the tangent line to the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ is vertical, so the normal line is horizontal.  Since the tangent line to the point $(0, \sqrt{0}) = (0, 0)$ is the $y$-axis, the normal line is the $x$-axis.

Comment: Very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  y' &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
  \text{slope of the normal} &=-2\sqrt{a} \\
  y-\sqrt{a} &= -2\sqrt{a}(x-a) \\
  2\sqrt{a}x+y &= \sqrt{a}(2a+1) \\
  \frac{x}{a+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{a}(2a+1)} &= 1 \\
  x\text{-intercept} &= a+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: The equation $2\sqrt{a}x + y = 2a - \sqrt{a}$ is incorrect.  It should read $2\sqrt{a}x + y = 2a\color{red}{\sqrt{a} +} \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Corrected, many thanks.